# Very small numbers in Fortran

Tags: fortran

Is it possible to achieve very small numbers in Fortran like `1E-1200`? I know how to do it in python, but my code for master's thesis runs too slow. My supervisor recommends me to use Fortran, but I am not sure if this is a problem.

Comment: I am a fortranner, but nevertheless, I would check whether the algorithm is fast enough. Changing the language does not make miracles, although some loops are slow in Python.

Comment: Hi @wafelos, It is often the case that when using an appropriate unit system (i.e. atomic units https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_units ) the range of floating point numbers becomes much more narrow. It is important to know as using 128 precision types will likely slow down you computations as they are not supported by the hardware.

Answer (score 5):

The previous answers suggesting use of REAL128 from ISO_FORTRAN_ENV describe a non-portable solution. What you would get here is a real type whose representation is 128 bits, but that says nothing about the range or precision of the type! For example, some IBM systems have a 128-bit real kind that is actually two doubles with an offset exponent. This gets you more precision but not significantly more range.

The proper way to do this is to use the SELECTED_REAL_KIND intrinsic function to determine the implementation's kind that supports the desired range. For example:

```
integer, parameter :: bigreal = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(R=1200)
real(KIND=bigreal) :: x
```

If the implementation doesn't have a real kind that can represent a value with a decimal exponent of plus or minus 1200, you'll get an error, otherwise you'll get the smallest appropriate kind.

You could also specify a P= value in the call to indicate what minimum precision (in decimal digits) you need.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes.

Modern compilers typically support so-called quad precision, a 128-bit real. A portable way to access this type is using the `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV`. Here is a sample program to show how big and small these numbers get:

```
program main
   use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, only : REAL32, REAL64, REAL128

   ! -- tiny and huge grab the smallest and largest
   ! -- representable number of each type
   write(*,*) 'Range for REAL32:  ',  tiny(1._REAL32),  huge(1._REAL32)
   write(*,*) 'Range for REAL62:  ',  tiny(1._REAL64),  huge(1._REAL64)
   write(*,*) 'Range for REAL128: ', tiny(1._REAL128), huge(1._REAL128)
end program main
```

The types `REAL32`, `REAL64`, and `REAL128` are typically known as single, double, and quad precision. Longer types have a larger range of representable numbers *and* greater precision.

On my machine with gfortran 4.8, I get:

```
mach5% gfortran types.f90 && ./a.out
 Range for REAL32:     1.17549435E-38   3.40282347E+38
 Range for REAL62:     2.2250738585072014E-308   1.7976931348623157E+308
 Range for REAL128:    3.36210314311209350626E-4932   1.18973149535723176502E+4932
```

As you can see, quad precision can represent numbers as small as `3.4E-4932`.

Answer (score 0):

Most Fortran compilers support REAL128 data format which matches IEEE binary128. Some support also REAL80 with similar range, matching C long double.  These don't have performance of REAL64 but should be much faster than python.

Comment: C doesn't specify which format should `long double` be, so are any other types. In MSVC `long double` is exactly the same as `double`. In platforms without 80-bit extended precision it may be IEEE-754 double precision or quadruple precision